# Recognizing the uniform from a video

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition

I am using **OpenCv** and **python**. I want to recognize a person that wear a particular uniform(white shirt + brown pants). I know how to recognize people (**HOGDescriptor**), but I don't know how to recognize the uniform that the person wear.

[image]

I have tried to use the feature matching (**BFMatcher**) and template matching(**matchTemplate**). However, they seems useless for detecting the uniform.

Is there any hints for me to detect the uniform(white shirt + brown pants).

Thank you.

Comment: did you solve this?